# Rails Automatically Signed In, Can't Log Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

SOLVED: Sorry guys, I solved it on my own by doing a db:reset and fixing one of the before filter methods that caused some issues.

Whenever I run my app on my localhost, I immediately am signed in. I tried this on multiple browsers and the same thing happens every time. The sign out function also does not work. I'm at a lost as to what to do. I have a repo of the app here... https://github.com/thejourneydude/template

My question is, why is my sign out function not working and why am I automatically signed in whenever I go to localhost? I am following Hartl's tutorial with some deviation so this should look familiar if you've done the tutorial.

Here is the sessions controller page...

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    #sign user in
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  else
    #create an error
    render 'new'
    flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
  end
end

def destroy
  sign_out
  redirect_to root_url
end

end
```

Here is the sessions helper page...

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(session[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    session.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end

end
```

Here is my User Model page

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { 
  case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}

  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private
     def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
     end

end
```

For kicks, here is my development log whenever I click on the sign out button.

```
Started DELETE "/signout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-09 20:38:32 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"i9mqiuYTW3YWxNU5h1RdtgTeb/2oOWPJU2yjjZQWMfw="}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-09 20:38:32 -0500
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE 
"users"."remember_token" IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 83ms (Views: 81.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Comment: Not an answer for your question, You can use devise or auth logic to to handle all signups and login stuff.

Comment: True, I want to do it from scratch though, or at least through Hartl's tutorials.

Comment: where is the method for authenticate defined in your model or code  Line number line 9 in sessions controller  ? user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

Comment: authenticate is apart of the `has_secure_password` method found in the `users.rb` of the Model.

Comment: Is that code hosted some where ?

Comment: `has_secure_password` is apart of Rails. More documentation can be found here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password

Comment: I am not able to find any bug in the code, that is why I have asked if the code is hosted some where ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I completely misread your comment. Besides github which was posted above, I don't. I'll create a Heroku app in 12 hours from now. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I uploaded it to Heroku, but it appears that Heroku isn't displaying my files. For instance, it defaults to the public.html page created by rails, when in fact I deleted the public.html ages ago and it won't let me route to any of the pages I created. So for now, heroku is out of the question.

Comment: I guess there is some silly mistake that is causing you all this trouble. I am not sure of it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing a db:reset and commenting out redirect_signed_in_user before filter method in Users controller. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem that I can see in the code that you have posted is that the current user method currently does not check for the existence of the remember_token in the session.

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(session[:remember_token])
  end
```

If the remember_token is not set the above code would result in a query which tries to find a user without a remember_token. If it finds such a user it would log that user in.

Although I see that you have a after_create callback for setting the remember token for users, it is possible that your development db might contain such a user which was created before you added the callback.

It might be a good idea to change your code in such a way that it checks for the existence of the remember_token before querying the db

```
def current_user
 if session_token[:remember_token]
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(session[:remember_token])
 end
end
```

Comment: Funny thing, I actually solved it. There was an issue with one of the before filter methods. I also did a `rake db:reset` where I plugged in all new users. Thanks for the help though and I'll take into consideration what you said for the remember_token.